# GAE DataStore referenceProperty relationship

Tags: python, google-app-engine, referenceproperty

I am trying to get all parent/children from a one to many relationship. Traditionally, I could do this with a join, but doing so in the datastore is escaping me.

I have found several partial examples to do this, but not one that is complete yet.

I have:

```
class Owner(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()

class Pet(db.Model):
  petname = db.StringProperty()
  owner = db.ReferenceProperty(Owner, collection_name='pets')

#now I want to print all pets owned by scott
scott = Owner(name="scott")
scott.put()
Pet(owner=scott,petname="rufus").put()

pets = Pet.all().filter('owner =', "scott").fetch(100)
print Pet.all().filter('owner =', "scott").fetch(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your query should work fine if you remove the quotes around "scott", I think.

You could also make all of Scott's Pet entities have his entity as their parent:

```
class Owner(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Pet(db.Model):
    petname = db.StringProperty()

scott = Owner(name="scott")
scott.put()

Pet(parent=scott, petname="rufus").put()
Pet(parent=scott, petname="fluffy").put()
Pet(parent=scott, petname="snoogums").put()

pets = Pet.all().ancestor(scott).fetch(100)
# Feed pets to your templating engine. So to speak.
```

By making scott the parent of the Pet entities, they are all added to the same entity group, and the `ancestor` query gives you a simple and stragihtforward way to get all of the `Pet` entities that are children of the given `Owner'. You should get much better performance with an ancestor query than a non-ancestor query.

This does impose the limitation that the Pet entities can only belong to one entity group, and if you wanted to have a `Pet` involved in multiple data relationships, you would have to choose another approach. If it is a one-to-one relationship, just storing a Reference to the other related entity.

To have a printable representation of your `Pet` entity, give it a `__unicode__` method, something like this:

```
class Pet(db.Model):
    petname = db.StringProperty()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "I am " + self.petname
```

`__unicode__` should return a string with the information that you want to see printed by the `print` statement. As Nick wisely points out in comments, you should not use `print` in an AppEngine application. The SDK comes with Django templates and Jinja2. Use one of those or import one that you prefer.

Comment: I think that might be what I am looking for, but how do I print them out?

If I just:
    print pets
I get: 
    [<__main__.Pet object at 0x10859df50>, <__main__.Pet object at 0x1085904d0>, <__main__.Pet object at 0x107bccb50>]

Comment: Answered your question, @stubblejumper

Comment: Note that `__repr__` is intended to return a 'code' representation of an object; `__unicode__` is the method to use for a human-readable representation - but you should probably use a templating system and output just the bits you care about in the current situation. And you really, really, really shouldn't use 'print' in an App Engine app.

Comment: In fact, `print` in an App Engine app is an almost automatic downvote from me, only the rest of Adam's answer is excellent. :)

Comment: That's funny, Nick. I almost always remember to encourage people not to use print, but because he asked it as a comment rather than as part of the actual question, I sort blanked out on that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [The GQL examples made by google](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference#Examples).

Use the owner name as unique key giving 'scott' to key_name instead of 'name' when instanciating Owner.

```
scott = Owner(key_name="scott")
```

Create the pet with scott as parent

```
pet = Pet(key_name='rufus', parent=scott)
```

And query his pets with

```
SELECT * FROM Pets WHERE ANCESTOR IS KEY('Owner', 'scott')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should filter by Key of Owner:

```
#not str "scott", use scott object.
pets = Pet.all().filter('owner =', scott).fetch(100)
```